# Multi row insert into multiple tables in a transaction using pg promise

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I am trying to perform a transaction using pg promise where I intend to insert multiple rows in multiple tables in the transaction. I am using pg promise helper methods to optimize the insert into each table but unable to concatenate all the queries together to perform only one query. Also would really appreciate if someone can point out if there is any way to further optimise the below code.

Currently I am getting an error that
**"Parameter 'queries' must be an array."** on pgp.hlpers.concat

```
db.tx(async t => {          
            let customerDataArray = [];
            let campaignStatusArray = [];
            let messageDetailsArray = [];

            for(const customer of customerDetails)
            {

                const customerData = {
                    columna1: customer.x,
                    columnb1: customer.y"
                };

                const campaignStatus = {
                    columna2: customer.a,
                    columnb2: customer.b
                };
                
                customerDataArray.push(customerData);
                campaignStatusArray.push(campaignStatus);

                for (const message of customer.messages)
                {
                    const messageStatus = {
                        columna: message.x,
                        columnb: message.y
                    };
                    messageDetailsArray.push(messageStatus);
                }
            }
            
            const customerDataCs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['columna1', 'columnb1'], {table: 'customerdata'});
            const campaignStatusCs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['columna2', 'columnb2'], {table: 'campaignstatus'});
            const messageStatusCs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['columna', 'columnb'], {table: 'messageStatus'});
            
            const customerDataQuery = pgp.helpers.insert(customerDataArray, customerDataCs);
            const campaignStatusQuery = pgp.helpers.insert(campaignStatusArray, campaignStatusCs);
            const messageStatusQuery = pgp.helpers.insert(messageDetailsArray, messageStatusCs);

            const concatAllQueries = pgp.helpers.concat(customerDataQuery, campaignStatusQuery, messageStatusQuery);

            await t.none(concatAllQueries);

        })
            .then(() => {
                // success;  
            })
            .catch(error => {
              
            });
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your queries to concat in a single array like so:

```
const concatAllQueries = pgp.helpers.concat([ customerDataQuery, campaignStatusQuery, messageStatusQuery ]);
```

Comment: You can see the documentation here: 
https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html

Comment: Yes sir thank you so much

Comment: Do you think there is a better way to further optimise this?

Comment: @SugarCode 1) You do not need to do that data re-mapping, you can remap within the `ColumnSet` instead. And 2) You can create the `ColumnSet` objects statically.

Comment: Hey Vitaly, first of all thank you so much for responding. Big fan. Sorry did not understand what you meant by data remapping, would you be able to point out with an example?

Comment: @SugarCode [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) constructor supports verbose data-mapping logic for its columns, which is where you can map to any data structure, no need to do that data preparation that you are doing.